# Is there a way to chain `Try` as a monad while also not catching exceptions raised along the chain?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The Scala `Try` construct together with its `flatMap` does not work as I would expect or want it to. The TL;DR is that I want to do a series of operations that can fail in two ways: either by raising an exception, which should be promoted and caught higher up in the call stack, or by returning `Failure`, as the failure must logically be handled in different parts of the program.

I would expect something like this to do the trick:

```scala
def firstStepSucceeds(): Try[Int] = Try {
  1
}

def secondStepThrows(input: Int) = {
  throw new Exception("Exception thrown in second step")
}

// I expect this to propagate the exception thrown in secondStepThrows
firstStepSucceeds() flatMap (secondStepThrows _)
```

([Full Scastie with example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9Nw2c2g4RXGCzIaqpxh31A))

However, in this case, the `flatMap()` call actually implicitly catches the uncaught exception thrown by `secondStepThrows`, which is not what I want (which is why I left out the `Try` block). Is there a way to get the same behaviour without the implicit exception-catching?

Comment: While I personally don't think it is a good idea to throw and exception in a method that returns a `Try` this behaviour is actually the reason why many folks prefer to use `Either` instead of `Try` and you may heard from functional folks that `Try` is not a valid `Monad` exactly for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens in a `Try` should stay in a `Try`. Most Scala programmers would be *very* surprised if a function returning a `Try` also sometimes threw an exception.

The typical pattern if you want to handle exceptions in different places is to differentiate by the type of the exception. So

```scala
val partiallyRecoveredTry = originalTry.recover{
  case _: SecondStepException => "second step had an exception"
}
// Further up the call stack
partiallyRecoveredTry.getOrElse("first step had an exception")
```

Comment: I would have accepted this without complaints if returns from within loops weren’t exceptions too.

Answer (score 0):

Try.flatMap() did not caught exceptions implicitely, it is the essence of Try.
When you use it, it is very explicit, and that's the goal.

I don't really understand what you want, but is something like that is possible for you ?

```
try {
  val first = firstStepSucceeds()
  val second = first.map(secondStepThrows).get
  val third = secondStepFails(second)
  // ...
}
catch {
  case e: Exception => ???
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it also reimplements flatMap in a very unsatisfying way by manually mapping and flattening.

Answer (score 0):

I did some further experimentation, and what I ended up with was this reimplementation of `Try` as (the now right-biased and hence monadic) `Either`:

```scala
object CatchAll {
  def apply[SomeType](block: => SomeType) = try { Right(block) }
  catch { case e: Throwable => Left(e) }
}

def firstStepSucceeds() = CatchAll {
  1
}

def firstStepFails() = CatchAll {
  throw new Exception("First step failed")
}

def secondStepSucceeds(input: Int) = CatchAll {
  input + 1
}

def secondStepFails(input: Int) = CatchAll {
  throw new Exception("Second step failed in try block!")
}

def secondStepThrows(input: Int) = {
  throw new Exception("Second step failed unexpectedly!")
}

firstStepSucceeds() flatMap (secondStepSucceeds _)
firstStepFails() flatMap (secondStepSucceeds _)
firstStepSucceeds() flatMap (secondStepFails _)

// This now throws an exception as expected
//firstStepSucceeds() flatMap (secondStepThrows _)
```